# c# (mono, dotgnu) for arm embedded questions

Tags: c#, .net, mono, embedded, arm

Has anyone experience with c# or .net based languages for arm based boards?

Are there compilers that make my code ready for the arm board?

Is it recommed to develop with linux or windows?

Are there advantages having a Linux, or Windows OS on the target board?

any help appreciated.
Thx

Comment: Are you talking about the [.Net micro framework](http://www.microsoft.com/netmf/default.mspx)? There are certainly ARM boards that support the micro framework. I don't think there is any mono support though.

Comment: Yes i include the .net micro framework, use it but the mfdeploy tool won´t connect to my arm board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download Mono and compile it for ARM.  The managed code (C#, etc) does not have to be recompiled for ARM, so you can develop it however you want, only the runtime needs to be ARM specific.

Mono (Novell) has commercial products for writing .Net apps for the iPhone/iPod/iPad (MonoTouch), and soon Android (MonoDroid), so ARM is a very well tested platform.

Comment: Note that in this case the Linux (or some other supported OS) is implied, and so you need a suitably powerful ARM CPU and enough RAM and Flash storage to boot the OS and Mono. I developed an embedded solution with a 500MHz CPU, 64 MB ram, and 16MB Flash which worked fine.

Comment: did any of you make a succesfull mono small-footprint build for arm?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer here:
[Using mono in embedded linux for hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668146/using-mono-in-embedded-linux-for-hardware/3676356#3676356)